# Does the motion of a simple pendulum shifts to SHM, due to damping?

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I have doubt in damping oscillations of a pendulum. Let's consider a simple pendulum in a drag medium like air. Suppose if the angular displacement (theta) is larger (say 40°), the oscillations start to occur, that its angular acceleration depends on -g/l.sin(theta). As the time increases the amplitude decreases, due to its air friction. My question is that, at once if the amplitude reaches the value less than 15° degrees (small approximations), does the pendulum executes SHM ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the energy loss due to friction per unit time t ~ observation time is much smaller than the total energy stored in the whole oscillating system, then you can approximate the oscillation being a simple harmonic motion (given that amplitude is small in a sense that you already outlined).

Comment: Well..in the case the energy loss per t is very small ,can be approximated

Answer (score 1):

By definition, [simple harmonic motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion) must have a fixed amplitude. If the amplitude of the pendulum's swing is decreasing over time due to air friction then its motion is a type of [complex harmonic motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_harmonic_motion) called *damped harmonic motion*. If the change in amplitude is very slow then over a short time period the amplitude of the pendulum's swing is approximately constant, and if the amplitude of the swing is small enough you can approximately model the motion of the pendulum as simple harmonic motion, although this will not be $100\%$ acurate.

Comment: Oh, Thank you. So Does complex harmonic motion, is combined behaviour of both anharmonic and harmonic right?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Within the small angle approximation (approx 15° or less), the restoring force is linear in $\theta$, just like a horizontal Hookian spring, $F=-kx$, which results in SHM.  Beyond 15° amplitude, the SHM approximation deviates significantly from the exact solution.

Comment: This answer is wrong since it is a damped oscillation

Comment: While your point is technically true, I wouldn't call the answer wrong.  The question seemed to focus on whether SHM was approximated in certain regimes of amplitude, which it is. Dampening can be modeled as a series of quasi static SHM amplitudes, or a SHM multiplied by an exponential.  If we want to be totally exact, even at small amplitudes the restoring force is proportional to $\sin\theta$ not $\theta$, so SHM is never completely correct for a pendulum. But it's nevertheless very useful for many predictions.